# EF Lazy loading not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

Entity and Component has one-to-many relationship. Entity stored in db correctly, with all components. But when I trying load it back this Entity in Child method Components not loads. If i try use lazy loading, code failing on entity.GetComponent because of Entity.Components isn't initialized. After exception Components are initialized and has zero elements. If I disable lazy loading, Components are initialized and has zero elements. I wrote example for building one-to-many relationship and using lazy initialization, and it works fine.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Parent();
    Child();
}

private static void Child()
{
    using (var db = new EntitiesContext())
    {
        var entities = from entity in db.Entities
                       select entity;

        foreach (Entity entity in entities)
        {
            Position pos = entity.GetComponent<Position>();
            Core core = entity.GetComponent<Core>();
        }
    }
}

private static void Parent()
{
    Entity entity = new Entity();

    entity.AddComponent(new Position(10, 10));
    entity.AddComponent(new ObjectName("Entity" + 1));
    entity.AddComponent(new Core(100));

    using (var db = new EntitiesContext())
    {
        db.Entities.Add(entity);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class EntitiesContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TypeMaskPair> MappedTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

    public EntitiesContext()
        : base("EntitiesDb")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
            .HasMany(entity => entity.Components)
            .WithRequired(component => component.EntityObj)
            .HasForeignKey(component => component.EntityId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        //this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
}

public abstract class Component
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Entity EntityObj { get; set; }

    private static DbMasksMapper componentsMap;

    static Component()
    {
        componentsMap = new DbMasksMapper(typeof(Component));
    }

    public TypeMask GetMask()
    {
        return componentsMap.GetMask(this.GetType());
    }

    public static TypeMask GetMask<T>() where T : Component
    {
        return componentsMap.GetMask(typeof(T));
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Component> Components { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public TypeMask Mask { get; private set; }

    public string TypeMaskString
    {
        get{ return Mask.ToString(); }
        set{ Mask = new TypeMask(value); }
    }

    public Entity()
    {
        Components = new List<Component>();
        Mask = new TypeMask();
    }

    public void AddComponent(Component component)
    {
        Components.Add(component);
        component.EntityObj = this;
        Mask |= component.GetMask();
    }

    public void DeleteComponent(TypeMask componentMask)
    {
        if (ContainsComponent(componentMask))
        {
            int removeIndex = Components.FindIndex(c => c.GetMask() == componentMask);
            Components.RemoveAt(removeIndex);
            Mask &= ~componentMask;
        }
    }

    public Component GetComponent(TypeMask componentMask)
    {
        return Components.Find(c => c.GetMask() == componentMask);
    }

    public T GetComponent<T>() where T : Component
    {
        return (T) GetComponent(Component.GetMask<T>());
    }

    public bool ContainsComponent<T>() where T : Component
    {
        return ContainsComponent(Component.GetMask<T>());
    }

    public bool ContainsComponent(TypeMask componentMask)
    {
        return (Mask & componentMask) == componentMask;
    }
}

class Position : Component
{
    public Position(int x = 0, int y = 0)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

class Cargo : Component
{
    public Cargo(int capacity = 0)
    {
        Capacity = capacity;
    }

    public int Capacity { get; set; }
}

class Core : Component
{
    public Core(int power = 0)
    {
        Power = power;
    }

    public int Power { get; set; }
}

class ObjectName : Component
{
    public ObjectName(string name = "")
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I saw similar questions, but didn't found any answer.

Where is a mistake?

**Solution**

All works after I wrote default constructor for inherited components. But, I don't understand why constructor with default arguments doesn't suitable. Without any argument it should work like default constructor. Can anyone explain it? Seems I doing it wrong

Comment: Because EF needs to create proxy classes for child entities and it can't do that without the presence of a public or protected parameterless constructor. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @AlaaMasoud, I know that. I don't understand why constructor with default arguments can't work like parameterless constructor?

Comment: Because EF doesn't know what to pass for those arguments.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud, so it doesn't unfold into separate constructors defenitions like in C/C++?

Comment: Default parameter values is just a trick. When the compiler generates the call it will provide the default values on the caller side. So after compilation there are no default parameter values anymore - all the parameter values are always passed. Hence ctors with default parameters are not equal to parameterless ctors.